Default urls exposed by .NET 8 web service
I have converted an Asp.Net, Framework 4.6.1, web service to a .NET 8 webservice using the .NET Upgrade Assistant and guidance here.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/porting/upgrade-assistant-overview
I cannot figure out the default url that the framework exposes for any given web service method.  I think that this should work for the following scenario:
http://192.168.1.222:7202/api/WsVersionNumber/GetWsVersionNumber
I am trying to hit this method: public string GetWsVersionNumber()
In this controller:
[ApiController]
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class WsVersionNumberController : ControllerBase
{
MyContext dbConn;
public WsVersionNumberController()
{
dbConn = new MyContext();
}
 
public static readonly string VERSION_NUMBER = "1.0.3.5";
 
[HttpGet]
public string GetWsVersionNumber()
{
return VERSION_NUMBER;
}

all of these urls return NOT FOUND in PostMan
http://192.168.1.222:7202/api/WsVersionNumber/GetWsVersionNumber
http://192.168.1.222:7202/api/GetWsVersionNumber
http://192.168.1.222:7202/WsVersionNumber/GetWsVersionNumber
I have found that if I put a Route attribute, with a route string in it, on a given web service method, I can get a corresponding url to hit that web service method fine.
NOTE: there is another [HttpGet] method in that controller, in case that matters. It has a Route on it and works fine
Here is my Program.cs file:
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using stkModelsCore.dbmsModels;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
builder.Services.AddSystemWebAdapters();

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();

builder.Services.AddDbContext<WjbeitlerContext>(options => 
options.UseSqlServer("data source = XXXXXX; initial catalog=MyDatabase;" +
"integrated security=SSPI; Connect Timeout = 90"), 
ServiceLifetime.Transient, ServiceLifetime.Transient);

var app = builder.Build();

if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseRouting();
app.UseAuthorization();
app.UseSystemWebAdapters();
app.MapControllers();
app.MapDefaultControllerRoute();
app.Run();

what url should hit the GetWsVersionNumber web service method, without putting a [Route] on that method?  Thanks.

The url that works is in the format of:
[api]/[ControllerName]

I was trying urls that were variations of:
[api]/[ControllerName]/[MethodName]

NOTES:

this is an HttpGet method
this is decorating the ws class: [Route("api/[controller]")]
if there are 2 HttpGet methods in that
controller, without [Route]s  it will throw:
"The request matched multiple endpoints."
If one of the HttpGet methods in the controller
has a [Route] the framework will find the method that does not have
the [Route]

